# How to execute a macro in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a requirement to move some of the existing frontend applications running Teradata as the backend to Google BigQuery. One of the common pattern used in these frontend applications is to call a Macro in Teradata, based on different input selected by users. Considering BigQuery doesn't have a way to create a macro entity, how can I replace this and have the frontend calling BigQuery to execute something similar. Connection to BigQuery is through ODBC/JDBC or java services.

Comment: If you need a single source of truth for a certain query with variables, you could just use any code management tool (github, ...) to save and retrieve it, no?

Comment: What does a MICRO usually do? How is it compared to a procedure with query parameters?

Answer (score 1):

A macro in `Teradata` is just a way to execute multiple SQL statements as a single request, which is in turn treated as a single transaction.  It also allows you to parameterize your query.

If your new DB backend supports it, you can convert the macros into stored procedures / functions.  Otherwise, you can pull out the individual SQL statements from the macro and try to run them together as a single transaction.

These links may be helpful: [Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions), 
[DML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language)

Glancing at the documentation, it looks like writing a function may be your best bet: "There is no support for multi-statement transactions."

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Bigquery scripting which is in Beta - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#bigquery-scripting for migrating your macros from Teradata. With this release you can write procedures where you can define all your business logic and then execute the procedure using a CALL statement.

Thanks,
Jayadeep

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above:

> A macro in Teradata is just a way to execute multiple SQL statements
>   as a single request, which is in turn treated as a single transaction.
>   It also allows you to parameterize your query.

Having said that, you just need to do the migrating part from teradata, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/teradata-migration) you can find the guide to do this, and answering your question, the connection is made through JDBC whose drivers are [tdgssconfig.jar and terajdbc4.jar](https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/jdbc-driver).